# How TCL stores variable in Memory

Tags: tcl

## file1.txt

```
dut1Loop1Net = [::ip::contract [::ip::prefix 1.1.1.1/24]]/24
```

## My script is

```
set in [open file1.txt r]  
set line [gets $in]  

if {[string trim [string range $line1 0 0]] != "#"} {  
    set devicePort [string trim [lindex $line1 0]]  
    set mark [expr [string first "=" $line1] + 1]  
    set val [string trim [string range $line1 $mark end]]  
    global [set t $devicePort]  
    set [set t $devicePort] $val  
}

close $in
```

## Problem

I am getting output as

```
% set dut1Loop1Net

[::ip::contract [::ip::prefix 1.1.1.1/24]]/24
```

Here i am getting the string without evaluating.
I am expecting the output as `1.1.1.0/24`. Because TCL does not evaluate code here, it is printing like a string.

I am interesting to know how TCL stores the data and in which form it will retreive the data.

Comment: Note that the command `::ip::contract [::ip::prefix 1.1.1.1/24]` gives you `1.1.1`, not `1.1.1.0`, so what your code *should* put into `dut1Loop1Net` is `1.1.1/24` and not `1.1.1.0/24`

Answer (score 4):

### How Tcl stores values.

- The short story:

  **[Everything is a string](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018)**
- The long strory

  Tcl stores the data in the last used datatype, calculate the string representation only when nessecary, uses copy on write, a simple refcount memory managment.

The answer how you evaluate it is with [`eval`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/eval.htm) or [`subst`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm). In your case probably [`subst`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm).

#### Edit:

If your config file looks like this:

```
# This is a comment
variable = value
othervar = [doStuff]
```

you can use some tricks to get Tcl parsing it for you:

```
rename ::unknown ::_confp_unknown_orig
proc unknown args {
    if {[llength $args] == 3 && [lindex $args 1] eq "="} {
        # varname = value
        uplevel 1 [list set [lindex $args 0] [lindex $args 2]
        return [lindex $args 2]
    }
    # otherwise fallback to the original unknown
    uplevel 1 [linsert $args 0 ::_confp_unknown_orig]
    # if you are on 8.6, replace the line above with
    # tailcall ::_confp_unknown_orig {*}$args
}
# Now just source the file:
source file1.txt
# cleanup - if you like
rename ::unknown {}
rename ::_confp_unknown_orig ::unknown
```

An other way to do that is to use a safe interp, but in this case using your main interp looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code you store inside `val` is never executed.

You access it using `$val`, but this way you get the code itself, and not the result of its execution.

To solve it, you must be sure `[::ip::contract [::ip::prefix 1.1.1.1/24]]/24` is executed, and you can do that by replacing this line

```
set val [string trim [string range $line1 $mark end]]
```

with this one

```
eval "set val [string trim [string range $line1 $mark end]]"
```

Why? Here's my simple explaination:

1. The parser sees the `"..."` part, so it performs substitutions inside it
2. The first substitution is the execution of the `string range $line1 $mark end` command
3. The second substitution is the execution of the `string trim ...` command

So, when substitutions are complete and the `eval` command is ready to run, its like your line has become

```
eval {set val [::ip::contract [::ip::prefix 1.1.1.1/24]]/24}
```

Now the `eval` command is executed, it calls recursively the interpreter, so the string `set val [::ip::contract [::ip::prefix 1.1.1.1/24]]/24` goes to another substitution phase, which *finally* runs what you want and puts the string `1.1.1/24` into the variable `val`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  but i need how the stored variable comes into the substitution (as list "" or {} or normal value) . Can u provide some good material for knowing the variable storing in the memory and to know which form ot has when it retrieves from  the memory . I know TCL concepts but some stuck in this issues .

Comment: From what I see in your question, you shouldn't need any knowledge of Tcl internals. Give a look at the links @JohannesKuhn wrote in his answer. Tcl variables are stored inside a C structure called `Tcl_Obj`. You can look at the sources to see how it's done: http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/dir?ci=2d4eff472ecdf29f&name=generic and see `tcl.h`